# Using Ember.js + Yeoman, where is a good place to put custom Handlebars helpers?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I don't see a recommendation in the guides about where to place custom Handlebars helpers within a project.

Comment: I simply added a "helpers" folder and then added that to the list of `require`d modules in "app.js".

Comment: @SteveH. Same here!  :-)  Sounds good to me.

Comment: I Would recommend using Ember-CLI :)

Comment: @prabhash , I would like to eventually!  :-)  I am new to Ember.js and SASS, and it was taking too long for me to figure out how to get SASS up and running with Ember-CLI.  Maybe for the next project.

Comment: `npm install ember-cli-bootstrap-sass` worked great for me, but you didn't say you used bootstrap...